# Orthogonality between distributions

Tags: python, vector, decision-tree, orthogonal

I'm implementing a decision tree algorithm and trying to use Orthogonality to measure the quality of a split.  My understanding is that I calculate Orthogonality as:

1−cosθ(Pi,Pj)

Where i is the partition of data before the split, and j is the partition after the split.  Pi and Pj are vectors of probabilities for each target value in each partition.

I've implemented the following but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this correctly.  I've got 6 classes and vector 1 has 66% in class 1, 33% in class 2 and none in the remaining classes.  Vectors 2 and 3 have the same distribution (40%, 10%,10%,20%,10%,10%)

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_orthogonality(vector_1, vector_2):

    dot_product = np.dot(vector_1, vector_2)
    orthogonality = 1 - np.cos(dot_product)

    return orthogonality

vector1 = [0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0]
vector2 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]
vector3 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]

print(calculate_orthogonality(vector1,vector2))
print(calculate_orthogonality(vector1,vector3))
print(calculate_orthogonality(vector2,vector3))

0.0446635108744
0.0446635108744
0.028662025148
```

In particular I would have expected vector2 and 3 to return 0 i.e. they're identical and therefore parallel.

This leads me to believe I've misunderstood something here.  Any ideas?

p.s. I have looked at other common measures such as gini impurity etc and they're fine but I've come across this as an alternative and I'm trying to measure it's effectiveness.

Cheers

David

EDIT:

Having found the following http://masongallo.github.io/machine/learning,/python/2016/07/29/cosine-similarity.html

it looks like I was way off in my understanding.  If I use this implementation I get the following

```
import numpy as np

def cos_sim(a, b):
    """Takes 2 vectors a, b and returns the cosine similarity according
    to the definition of the dot product
    """
    dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
    norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
    norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
    return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)

vector1 = [0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0]
vector2 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]
vector3 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]

print(cos_sim(vector1,vector2))
print(cos_sim(vector1,vector3))
print(cos_sim(vector2,vector3))

0.821583836258
0.821583836258
1.0
```

Vectors 2 and 3 are highlighted as being the same.  I need to understand a bit more about the process but I think this is correct.

Comment: Yes, you do not need to calculate the `cos`. The cos converts the *angle* of two vectors to the dot product divided by the product of the length of the two vectors. But you here calculate the cos of the dot product. Which makes semantically not much sense.

Comment: Furthermore can you point to where it states that the orthogonality is 1-cos(theta)?

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem, that makes sense.  As is often the case, after asking a question I think I've stumbled upon the answer here:http://masongallo.github.io/machine/learning,/python/2016/07/29/cosine-similarity.html - I'll update the answer.  And to your second comment, I think again this is my misunderstanding of the calculation

Comment: You can answer your own questions, which indicates to other SO users that there is no need to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay - the answer was indeed to use the code as per the edit

```
import numpy as np

def cos_sim(a, b):
    """Takes 2 vectors a, b and returns the cosine similarity according
    to the definition of the dot product
    """
    dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
    norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
    norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
    return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)

vector1 = [0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0]
vector2 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]
vector3 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]

print(cos_sim(vector1,vector2))
print(cos_sim(vector1,vector3))
print(cos_sim(vector2,vector3))

0.821583836258
0.821583836258
1.0
```